# Ubuntu cannot read AIFF information

Tags: files, music, apple

I have Apple Lossless songs that I use for my iPod, and Ubuntu sees the files, but does not recognize any information related to the songs. They show up as Unknown Artist, Album, etc.

I have tried converting the songs with Audacity, but even after the conversion, there is still no info about the file information. Ubuntu sees MP3 data just fine, but I want my lossless songs for my iPod. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the package `sox` by using the terminal. Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> and use the command:

```
 sudo apt-get install sox
```

The [description of the packages shows this info](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man7/soxformat.7.html):

> Format types that can SoX can determine by  a  filename  extension  are
>          listed  with  their  names  preceded  by  a dot.  Format types that are
>           optionally built into SoX are marked `(optional)'.
>    ......
>    ......
>    ......
>
> .aiff, .aif (also with -t sndfile)
>             AIFF  files  as  used on old Apple Macs, Apple IIc/IIgs and SGI.
>                 SoX's AIFF support does not include multiple  audio  chunks,  or
>                 the  8SVX musical instrument description format.  AIFF files are
>                 multimedia archives and can  have  multiple  audio  and  picture
>                 chunks  -  you  may  need a separate archiver to work with them.
>                 With Mac OS X, AIFF has been superseded by CAF.

Hope this will fix the problem. You may also try using kid3 package. [Download and install it from here](http://kid3.sourceforge.net/)